# Memory management issue with image upload for dash web app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, pytorch, plotly-dash

I built a computer vision web app and deployed it on Heroku.
It processes picture uploaded by a user (through dcc.upload) and should return the processed picture and additional information computed by a PyTorch back-end.

After a few picture uploads, I bumped into memory issue and the app crashed. My understanding is that all pictures passed through dcc.upload are accumulated into memory ([see here](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-upload-component-decoding-large-files/8033/5)) and causes the crash.

Here an overview of the code:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    
    ...
    
        dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-image',
        children=html.Div(['Drag and Drop or ',
                           html.A('Select Files')]),
        ...
        
        ),
    ...
    
    ])

@app.callback(
    [Output('output-image-1', 'children'),
      Output('output-image-2', 'children'),
      Output('output-graph', 'children')],
    [Input('upload-image', 'contents')])
def update_output(content):
    
    if content is not None:
        
        # Deep Learning
        raw_img, grad_img, d_probs = process(content)
        return parse_image(str_raw_img), parse_image(str_grad_img), parse_graph(d_probs)
    
    else:
        return None, None, None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

How could I improve memory management? Ideally, pictures could be deleted whenever a new one is uploaded. I understand I could use [dcc.Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) but I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Asset uploading, image processing etc will always consume a lot of RAM. Even more so, when concurrent users are performing the same action. Amazon AWS provides direct upload facility https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/ so as the upload doesn't go anywhere near your running application. Once the upload is complete your application would receive a notification upon which you can then spawn a background worker to do whatever processing you need.

Comment: I think the author is looking for a way to delete the previously uploaded picture from RAM once a new one is uploaded. I.e. the question is about managing RAM within the dash web app (clearing "cache") rather than about storing and then processing. There are cases where it is necessary to avoid actually storing the uploaded content in a remote location.